# array on curve deforming my mesh

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I'm trying to make these triangle pieces for the "sun rays" be on a curve and arrayed around the sphere or "sun" model.

[image: this is before the array and curve modifier]

The image above is before the modifiers on but some reason after I enable it and set it correctly I think... it appears all deformed and weird!

[image]

I don't know why it's doing that. Please note position and scale is already applied to everything so I know that isn't the problem. Also note origin barely doesn't anything to my solutions because it still gives me the same problems...

[image]

Here's the .blend file if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You've scaled your curve, as you've applied the scale it has changed the vertices radius up to the scale value. What you need to do is bring the vertices radius down to 1, either in the *N* panel or with right click > *Set Curve Radius* and press 1:

[image]

Comment: what version of blender is that? I'm not seeing those options when I press "n".

Comment: you need to select the curve and switch to Edit mode

Comment: question 2 when i apply the curve modifier why does my mesh changes

Comment: because if you apply the scale of a curve that was, let's say, x3, it will change the vertices radius to 3 instead of 1, and the size of the object or instances that are linked to the curve by a Curve modifier is determined by the radius of this curve vertices